# basename extra operand in GitHub actions

Tags: bash, github-actions, zsh

I have a shell script that is supposed to dynamically bundle and zip binaries based on the directory names in `cmd/`

When using the script locally, it works like a charm. However when the script is ran in github actions, I get the error

```bash
basename: extra operand ‘./cmd/get-reminders/’
```

I have a function that collects all dir names and pushes them to an array. The error above is happening when this function is ran.

```bash
prepare() {
    for d in "./cmd/*/"
    do 
        handlers+=($(basename $d))
    done
}
```

Any ideas what the error actually is, and why github actions throws this error, and why its not happening locally?

I'm running `zsh` locally, github uses. `bash`. I don't think that's the problem, but I'm mentioning it anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: The loop does not make sense. It is executed only once, with `d` being set to the string `./cmd/*/`. This means that you actually execute a `basename ./cmd/*/`, which bash expands to all files matching this pattern. If the number of files is greater than 2, `basename` complains about the error. Under `zsh`, this latter expansion would not occur, and you don't get an error (the script just produces a non-sense output).

Comment: Adding to my comment: By all means, avoid having one script run as "bash" in one occasion and as "zsh" in a different context. This is a bit like running one program on odd days under Java and on even days under Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was looping over a path inside quotes.

`for d in "./cmd"` does not work in some shell.
Correct would be `for d in ./cmd`

Comment: The `*` does not expand within quotes, it is treated as a literal `*` and not a glob at least in a POSIX compliant shell...

Comment: Good point. That's probably the reason. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: Remove the quotes or put the glob `*` outside, e.g. `"./cmd/"*`, Also have a look at `nullglob` shell option from bash. Try `PAGER='less +/^\ *nullglob' man bash
`